# Couldn't run in dev mode GWT

Tags: gwt, development-mode

I have a GWT project and I can run it via hosted mode of build.xml. 
But in case I don't have it(projects that I created by eclipse plugin) I run it by running com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.class file but it says :
Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997

why? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have the Eclipse plugin, you can use it to run your project as a GWT app. Right click on your project or `module.gwt.xml` file > Run as > GWT Application. If you have multiple modules, it will let you pick a module, and it might ask you to pick the hosted html file.

Doing that will use the Devmode class to run your app.